# Why "have welcomed", but not "has welcomed"?

Tags: british-english

In book "Agents of Empire: Knights, Corsairs, Jesuits and Spies in the Sixteenth-Century Mediterranean World" Written by: Noel Malcolm, there is this sentence:

> Sultan Suleyman the Magnificent was apparentlly spoiling for a fight with Venice, and may even ***have welcomed*** an incident in early 1537 when a hot-headed Venecian naval commander, Alesandro Conferini, attaced three Ottoman ships and sank 
>   two of them, the realy giving Suleyman a pretext for war.

My question is: Why author, british-english native, write "have welcomed", but no "has welcomed".

Comment: The author wrote a form of _**may have welcomed**_ – the _may_ is a modal verb.

Comment: The verb which follows a modal verbs is **always** in the infinitive form.

Comment: The "have" is associated with "may", as in "may have", rather than with "welcomed", as you have it bolded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you don't see that the whole verb in the sentence is **may have welcomed**. We usually use an infinitive after modal verbs. **May** is a modal verb and **have welcomed** is a perfect infinitive.

Comment: I would mention the interfering "even".